# prevent passbook keeps retrying when receiving an http error code.

Tags: http, passbook

When passbook receives an error (i.e. HTTP 500 ERROR) it keeps retrying until the end of times. Is there a way to make it stop doing that in iOS6?
What response or HTTP code will make it stop.

Comment: Why is it getting an error? Are you returning an error from your service?

Comment: Yes, we are sending an error due to the data is not longer available.

Comment: One option might be to push an updated pass that no longer includes a WebServiceURL.